# Image CSS transition on :before

Tags: html, css

As you can see, hover on the "About" link and a sub-nav appears to fly out from the left. On the other side of that sub-nav (opposite to the sub-nav links) I want an image (http://placehold.it/30x100) to fly out (transition) from the right. So far everything I've tried doesn't work.

http://codepen.io/matthewmorrisux/pen/wMMpzE

```
<div class="container">
  <nav class="menu">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/240x60" alt="" class="menu__img" />
    <ul>
      <li class="menu__item">
        <a href="">About</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <div class="sub-menu__items">
            <li class="sub-menu__item"><a href="">item 1</a></li>
            <li class="sub-menu__item"><a href="">item 2</a></li>
            <li class="sub-menu__item"><a href="">item 3</a></li>
            <li class="sub-menu__item"><a href="">item 4</a></li>
          </div>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu__item"><a href="">Process</a></li>
      <li class="menu__item"><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>



.container {
  position: relative;
}

ul, li, a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.menu img {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  /* left: 10%; */
}

.menu ul {
  text-align: center;
}


.menu__item {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 40px;
}

.sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height .5s ease 1s;
}

.menu__item:hover .sub-menu {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  transition: height .5s ease 0s;
}

.sub-menu:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 0px;
  background: black;
  transition: height .2s ease .5s;
}

.menu__item:hover .sub-menu:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
  transition: height .3s ease 0s;
}

.sub-menu__items {
  position: relative;
  left: -110px;
  transition: left .2s ease .3s;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font: 700 16px/21px arial;
}

.menu__item:hover .sub-menu__items {
    left: 0px;
    transition: left .2s ease .4s;
}

.sub-menu__item {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 5px;
  left: -100px;
  transition: left .2s ease .4s;
}

.menu__item:hover .sub-menu__item:nth-of-type(1) {
  left: 0px;
  transition: left .2s ease 0s;
}

.menu__item:hover .sub-menu__item:nth-of-type(2) {
  left: 0px;
  transition: left .2s ease 500ms;
}

.menu__item:hover .sub-menu__item:nth-of-type(3) {
  left: 0px;
  transition: left .2s ease 600ms;
}

.menu__item:hover .sub-menu__item:nth-of-type(4) {
  left: 0px;
  transition: left .2s ease 700ms;
}
```

[image]

Comment: you know you can download that zip file right

Comment: what do you mean a cross fade

Comment: Opposite where? It's not clear how this is supposed to look...do you have a design image we could refer to? Also the codepen doesn't really show what you have tried to resolve this,

Comment: @Paulie_D I have added an image to show how it should work. I erased the code I did have to not confuse you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Updated: I believe the issue you had is due to the overflow hidden. I have made a few tweaks and I think the outcome is now very close to what you've asked.

[See here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxeNBv)

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  font: bold 18px/21px arial;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

ul, li, a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.menu img {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  /* left: 10%; */
}

.menu ul {
  text-align: center;
}


.menu__item {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 40px;
}

.sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  transition: height .5s ease 1s;
}

.menu__item:hover .sub-menu {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  transition: height .5s ease 0s;
}


.sub-menu:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 0px;
  background: black;
  transition: height .2s ease .5s;
}

.menu__item:hover .sub-menu:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
  transition: height .3s ease 0s;
}

.sub-menu__items {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  transition: left .2s ease .3s;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font: 700 16px/21px arial;
}

.sub-menu__items:before {
  content:'';
  width:0;
  height:100px;
  background: url('http://placehold.it/30x100');
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:100%;
  margin-left:-30px;
  display: block;
  transition: width 0.3s ease;
}
.menu__item:hover .sub-menu__items:before {
  width: 30px;
}
.menu__item:hover .sub-menu__items {
    left: 0px;
    transition: left .2s ease .4s;
}

.sub-menu__item {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 5px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .2s ease .4s;
}

.menu__item:hover .sub-menu__item:nth-of-type(1) {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .2s ease 200ms;
}

.menu__item:hover .sub-menu__item:nth-of-type(2) {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .2s ease 500ms;
}

.menu__item:hover .sub-menu__item:nth-of-type(3) {
 opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity  .2s ease 600ms;
}

.menu__item:hover .sub-menu__item:nth-of-type(4) {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity  .2s ease 700ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <nav class="menu">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/240x60" alt="" class="menu__img" />
    <ul>
      <li class="menu__item">
        <a href="">About</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <div class="sub-menu__items">
            <li class="sub-menu__item"><a href="">item 1</a></li>
            <li class="sub-menu__item"><a href="">item 2</a></li>
            <li class="sub-menu__item"><a href="">item 3</a></li>
            <li class="sub-menu__item"><a href="">item 4</a></li>
          </div>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu__item"><a href="">Process</a></li>
      <li class="menu__item"><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: I have added an image for further clarification. Thanks.